# Fitting a sigmoid model to my data and comparing parameters for different factors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, modeling, sigmoid-curve

I acquired data from 20 subjects for 4 different conditions (2 factors) with 14 different intensity levels, created using a log-space distribution. I would like to model the response for each condition across all the levels for the 4 conditions using a sigmoid function $f(x)={\frac {L}{1+e^{-k(x-c)}}}$ where $k$ is the steepness of the curve and $c$ is the midpoint and $L$ the max value of $y$.  So, your basic logistic curve. I want to find out if these parameters are significantly different across conditions.

Here is a plot of the data.
[image]

As you can see, the data is quite noisy, but this is to be expected. I am investigating brain-related responses to image manipulations using electroencephalography (EEG).

My problem is not one of coding but understanding what statistical approach to follow. One approach I considered was to fit this model to this data and then look at RMSE and R-squared values, if they look good, then to fit this model at an individual subject basis and acquire the parameters. Then input into an ANOVA to find an interaction between my conditions.

Just using the RMSE and R-squared values seems a bit arbitrary, so I was wondering if there is a way of knowing that my model significantly predicts the data (like having a p-value) before moving on to the individual data fitting.

Also, if you know of other ways modeling this data, it would be great - like using generalized linear models.

Comment: These curves seem to be bounded above.  Is there a theoretical bound to these values?

Comment: The nature of the "noise" matters.  How are the measurements made and what is the source of the noise?

Comment: @DemetriPananos thank you for your question. What do you mean bounded above? Are you referring to the upper asymptote? If so, this represents the saturation of the EEG responses to stimuli. In essence, increasing the intensity of the stimulus does not lead to any further increase in the brain responses.

Comment: @whuber The nature of the noise is related to the variability of response to the different stimuli intensities across participants. When using EEG across several participants it is difficult to acquire data that behaves consistently. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Because the description is vague and non-quantitative it doesn't fully answer my question, but it does seem to confirm a suspicion that the noise is *heteroscedastic,* indicating you should look for an appropriate GLM or maximum likelihood fit rather than a least squares fit.

Comment: @whuber, I am sorry that I was unable to answer your question fully. Is there a particular piece of information that I can give you regarding the noise issue? For me, it's difficult to add any more to that because of the nature of my experiment. I also looked using GLM, but what I understood is that if you conduct a logistic regression, it will expect values ranging from 0 to 1 as the GLM will predict the probability of an event occurring. In my data, this is not really the case. Maybe I am totally wrong here; I am quite new to using pre-determined models for analysis.

Comment: A good way to approach problems like this is to understand the experiment and the measurement system so you can accurately model its variability.  This is the *opposite* of a "pre-determined model."  As a (simplified) example, a consumer digital camera measures photons and amplifies those measurements electronically.  The physics of photon emission and detection imply Poisson "shot noise" in their variability and the physics of the electronics suggest additional nearly Gaussian "white noise" is added to that, giving a good statistical model for analysis.

Comment: @whuber Ok, thanks for the tips :). I'll investigate further how to best approach my problem.